# Should WebDAV server support HEAD on folders?

Tags: request, webdav, head

I have discovered that one of the WebDAV clients is sending HEAD request to WebDAV folder (collection). The WebDAV server that I am testing with does not support HEAD on folders and responds with HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed. The WebDAV client fails to connect.

```
[Request]
HEAD /
Connection: Keep-Alive
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Host: localhost:5182

[Response]
HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed
```

Should WebDAV server support HEAD on folders or is it a WebDAV client bug?

Answer (score 2):

From RFC 2616

> The HEAD method is identical to GET except that the server MUST NOT
>   return a message-body in the response. The metainformation contained
>   in the HTTP headers in response to a HEAD request SHOULD be identical
>   to the information sent in response to a GET request

This suggests that HEAD should only be supported on a resource if GET is supported.

Many servers won't implement GET on folders, so it would be reasonable to not implement HEAD. So to me this sounds like a client-side bug.

Clients should instead do OPTIONS for capability discovery.

Comment: This means that HEAD requests should return headers and no body, not no response at all.

Answer (score 2):

RFC4918 states :

> Similarly, since the definition of HEAD is a GET without a response message body, the semantics of HEAD are unmodified when applied to collection resources.

So yes, it should support it.

http://www.webdav.org/specs/rfc4918.html#rfc.section.9.4

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It is required by RFC 2616.

Answer (score 1):

A HEAD method is basically a "What are the headers going to be if I call GET?" Now it is true that it is up the the WebDAV server to determine what it should return for a GET on a folder. It is almost always either an index (in html format) or a "not found" response (404). Sending "method not allowed" is not really a good implementation. This implies that directory browsing is not allowed, which makes absolutely no sense on a WebDAV server. In other words, a HEAD request on a folder should almost always return an HTML index (minus the response body) or a 404 error. The purpose of the 404 is to notify the client that there is no document that matched that last segment of the requested url.

Comment: Agreed, except that a 404 doesn't make any sense if the collection exists.

Comment: Well, it depends on the HTTP method. If you (a WebDAV server) receive a GET request on a collection (a folder), what should you return? An html index file? A compressed folder/zip file with the entire contents of the collection? Most WebDAV servers treat the GET method (and subsequently HEAD methods) as a request for a resource, not as a method of discovery. That is what PropFind is for. In other words, a successful GET method should return content and the servers that return html index files do it as a convenience for the client (in case they are using a web browser), not for conformity.

Comment: Paul Easter: in doubt, return a blank page. But do not say 404 when there indeed is a resource at that URI.

Comment: @JulianReschke I did not say to return 404 on something that exists. I said do not respond to a GET method with a 405 (method not allowed). I said that 404 was one of two proper response codes for a GET request (in WebDav)